# How to play an encrypted AVI file 

Tags: encryption, decryption, video-codecs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encryption of a movie file.](https://superuser.com/questions/243044/encryption-of-a-movie-file)

I have downloaded a movie form a torrent, which is in an [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) file (file size 1.3 GB) format. I used [VLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) to open the file, but it didn't play and showing the message "This video is encrypted please download the codec". How can I play the file? Any method to decrypt it?

Comment: Did it say what it was encrypted with?

Comment: Is that a *real* VLC message or something on the video?  I agree with the comments about malware.  If I had the guts to run it, it would be in a VM or junk isolated machine.

Comment: The AVI container provides NO facility for content encryption, the file cannot possibly be encrypted, that is why some companies are using WMV and other formats for distribution. It is just a scam to get you to download malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file appears to be very suspicious for all the reasons stated by Matt Schweers and I would caution against opening the file using a third party codec as these are a common conduit for malware installation.

Assuming that you are aware of the potential risks associated with opening this file and you still wish to do so, I would suggest the use of a VM that is fully isolated from the host system (i.e. No network or host integration features enabled) so that any malware that might execute as a result of installing the codec would be isolated from the host system as well as any other systems on your network or the internet.

Comment: hey! thank u too..@Crippledsmurf  i will do so..

Comment: I have also used Sandboxie as a solution to isolate executables/media files from time-to-time. I find it quicker than firing up a VM when I just need it to do a trial-and-error test on a file

Answer (score 6):

Three things I find normally find fishy about media files from torrents (music/video/otherwise):

1. VLC won't open the file
2. Encryption that is not based on a password
3. Any mention of a 'special' codec

I would stay far away from this file and find a different version of it elsewhere. The danger is probably not the file itself, but whatever 'codec' you have to download will inevitably contain some kind of malware. Though, if you can provide more specific information about the encryption, someone more informed than myself may have a better answer for you

[This is what McAfee have to say about infoavi.com](http://www.siteadvisor.com/sites/infoavi.com/msgpage)

> Malicious site listed at freepcsecurity.co.uk - keep clear.
>   It is one of the malicious and rogue sites which may compromise your PC Security. Some may contain driveby downloads, trojans, backdoor bots, rootkits, rogue programs (PUP�s), unwanted adware/spyware and all are to be considered a threat.
>
> WARNING THIS SITE POSES SERIOUS SECURITY THREATS: Threats on this and other malware sites may include fake antivirus scams, malicious redirects, viruses, trojans, rogue installers, key loggers, droppers, browser exploits, and a range of other security threats. Avoid malware sites. Do not become their next victim.
>
> This site has a link to download a supposed "codec" in order to watch certain video formats. After downloading the .exe file, which already had me concerned, my anti-virus software identified the .exe file as a trojan and immediately removed it.

Comment: Are you sure that,"whatever 'codec' you have to download will inevitably contain some kind of malware"? I have downloaded codecs and never had malware. Perhaps I'm an exception?

Comment: @Xavier - Are you *sure* you are an exception :-) When was the last time you scanned your computer.

Comment: @Nifle - Thanks for the supporting documentation, this seems like the exact type of security risk I was implying.

Comment: @nifle. I scan it every night using both Malwarebyte and Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: @Xavierjazz it's the site itself that can contain the malware, not something that you would explicitly download from it. You open the site in the browser, it exploits a 0-day vulnerability and you are toasted.