# Encrypted avi file (movie)

Tags: avi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encryption of a movie file.](https://superuser.com/questions/243044/encryption-of-a-movie-file)

I have downloaded an avi movie and I have been asked to look for the video codec in u website

Comment: What website is it directing you to go to?

Comment: "in u website"?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [VLC Media PLayer](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

It is capable of playing (almost?) any video file, and should definitely be able to play your video.

If you didn't want to try a different player, and you are on:

**Windows:** you should be able to use [The Combined Community Codec Pack](http://www.cccp-project.net/) to play the video in your player of choice.
**OSX:** you should be able to play the video in Quicktime after installing [Perian](http://perian.org/).

Comment: If VLC won't play a video, chances are nothing else will.

Comment: @MBraedley: Exactly. I have never come across a video that VLC won't play.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of some "films" simply being videos directing you to go a random website on the internet and download a codec from there and install it,  whereby they can potentially install a virus and other malicious software onto your computer.  While this may not be the case for you it is a possibility.

I'd go with Azz and try playing it with VLC, if that can't figure out what the file is and play at least some of it then more likely than not the file is bogus.